# Is it Haram to play a game with interest?

Tags: riba

So I play this game Hypixel Skyblock on Minecraft, and it has a bank that lets you gain interest. So would that make it haram for me to play it and if so, would it still be Haram if I stopped using the bank and kept the coins in my inventory.